# Send file directly to google drive using api and input file

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I'm uploading files to google drive using api, but actually i have the follow method:

- Send the file to the server using file input
- Send file from server to google drive using api

I have this coding working for what i mentioned above. (the code is inside of one framework)

```
public function actionCallgdrive() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Drive");
    $client->setAuthConfig((dirname(__FILE__)) . '/client_secret.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . Url::to(['content/callgdrive']));
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $this->redirect($auth_url);
    } else {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $this->redirect(['content/google-drive']);
    }
}

public function actionGoogleDrive($filename) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Drive");
    $client->setAuthConfig((dirname(__FILE__)) . '/client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $refreshToken = $this->getRefreshTokenFromDatabase();
            $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
            $newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
            $newAccessToken['refresh_token'] = $refreshToken;
            $this->setRefreshTokenIntoDatabase($newAccessToken);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $newAccessToken;
        }
        set_time_limit(0);
        $gdrive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $folderId = 'dfghjtyguygyuuuuuuuuuuu';
        $file->setName($filename);
        $file->setParents([$folderId]);
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        $client->setDefer(true);
        $request = $gdrive_service->files->create($file);

        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $client, $request, 'application/zip', null, true, $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/content/' . $filename));

        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/content/' . $filename, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        $result = false;
        if ($status != false) {
            $result = $status;
            $fileId = $result->getId();
        }
        fclose($handle);
        $client->setDefer(false);

    } else {
        $this->actionCallgdrive();
    }
}

public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/content/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
            $filename = $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension;
            $this->actionGoogleDrive($filename);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

**So, my question is:** I can send file directly to google drive using file input? If yes, how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

**"can I send file directly to google drive using file input? If yes, how i can do it?"**

I think this is doable by using the [Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) method and specifying the MIMEtype of the file as application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.

Since you're looking for a PHP sample, try this one from the guide:

```
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  // Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }

  try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the unique reply.
I tried that method before and i got this error: "Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Resource_Files::insert()" i think that method is from old api version.